# CCBlinkTo in SpriteKit

Tags: objective-c, swift, sprite-kit

How can I achieve CCBlink like action in Sprite-Kit ? I want 10 blink in 2.

```
id blink = [CCBlink actionWithDuration:2.0f blinks:10];
id calBck = [CCCallBlock actionWithBlock:^{
           [enemy expired];
    }];
[HeroSprite runAction:[CCSequence actions:blink, calBck, nil]];
```

Comment: use a runBlock action that toggles the hidden property

Comment: Or a sequence of very short fades.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This example uses the `alpha` property to create the blink effect. You might as well use the `hidden` property and a runBlock action, as @LearnCocos2D suggested.

Blink time: 2.0 / 10 = 0.2, so 0.1 seconds for each fade-in and fade-out.

```
    HeroSprite.alpha = 0.0;

    SKAction *blinkSequence = [SKAction sequence:@[
        [SKAction fadeAlphaTo:1.0 duration:0.1],
        [SKAction fadeAlphaTo:0.0 duration:0.1]
    ]];


    [HeroSprite runAction:[SKAction repeatAction:blinkSequence count:10] completion:^{
        [enemy expired];
    }];
```

Answer (score 1):

I've translated to **Swift** 2.x the [S.E.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22423879/1894067) answer but **I want also colorize** my node during the blinking. The problem was when you have to do with different types of node.

I've solved and make this extension with this code:

```
// SKAction extension : blink effect for a generic SKNode, SKShapeNode, SKSpriteNode and SKLabelNode
// Usage:
// self.runAction(SKAction.blink(5)) // fade in and fade out 5 times for 2 seconds
// self.runAction(SKAction.blink(5, duration: 3.0)) // fade in and fade out 5 times for 3 seconds or whatever you want
// self.runAction(SKAction.blink(5, duration: 3.0, colorize: true)) // fade in and fade out 5 times for 3 seconds switching color from red to white
// self.runAction(SKAction.blink(5, duration: 3.0, colorize: true, color1:SKColor.blueColor(), color2:SKColor.yellowColor())) // fade in and fade out 5 times for 3 seconds switching color from custom color2 to custom color1
extension SKAction {
    class func blink(times:Int,duration:NSTimeInterval = 2.0,colorize:Bool = false, color1:SKColor = SKColor.redColor(),color2:SKColor = SKColor.whiteColor())->SKAction {
        let fadeOut = SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(0.0, duration: (duration/Double(times))/2)
        let fadeIn = SKAction.fadeAlphaTo(1.0, duration: (duration/Double(times))/2)
        if colorize {
            var isColorChanged = false
            let colorize = SKAction.customActionWithDuration(0.01, actionBlock: {
                    node, elapsedTime in
                    switch node {
                    case is SKSpriteNode:
                        if !isColorChanged {
                            node.runAction(SKAction.colorizeWithColor(color2, colorBlendFactor: 1, duration: 0.01))
                        } else {
                            node.runAction(SKAction.colorizeWithColor(color1, colorBlendFactor: 1, duration: 0.01))
                        }
                    case is SKShapeNode:
                        (node as! SKShapeNode).fillColor = isColorChanged ? color1 : color2
                    case is SKLabelNode:
                        (node as! SKLabelNode).fontColor = isColorChanged ? color1 : color2
                    default:
                        break
                    }
            })
            let changeColor = SKAction.runBlock({
                isColorChanged = !isColorChanged
            })
            let blink = SKAction.sequence([fadeOut,colorize, fadeIn, changeColor])
            return SKAction.repeatAction(blink, count: times)
        }
        let blink = SKAction.sequence([fadeOut, fadeIn])
        return SKAction.repeatAction(blink, count: times)
    }
}
```